# finding /obtaining a "half equation" to a mathematical problem / expression

Tags: string, numbers, fractions

I am trying to figure out a software program I can use that will give me the full decimal numbers in the half equation in expression thaty have long , repeating decimals that get shortened in almost every calculator. I was told to use a TI86 and use the DHS screen to get to the list of strings (full numbers / decimals that are not rounded) as it is being solved, step by step.

I am not a methmatical wiz, and need some guidance here. I cannot find anywhere that talks about a DHS menu and I cannot figure out how to do this and what programs, windows , linux or emulators can do it. I do know that the TI86 6is the calculator that can do it. But I couldn't figure it out.

I am guessing this is sort of like a memory dump. I hope I am being clear enough. IF not let me know where I lost you. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

I have tried a TI86 emulator and after getting the expression solved, I then wanted to enter the mode that lets me get the full decimal numbers that were processed during that equation. I couldn't find it anywhere , but I have no experience with TI86.